# On my motherboard 4 SATA drives work but the 4 others don't

Tags: motherboard, sata

I have this motherboard  **Intel® Desktop Board D975XBX2**, for which here is the [manual](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/d975xbx2/sb/CS-023492.htm)   .

The manual says it has:

```
Eight Serial ATA channels (one device per channel):   

Four RAID capable Serial ATA (3.0 Gb/s) connectors (black) via the ICH7DH  

Three RAID capable Serial ATA (3.0 Gb/s) connectors (blue) via 
the Marvell RAID controller   

One RAID capable Serial ATA (3.0 Gb/s) connector via the Marvell 
RAID controller, compatible with an external Serial ATA drive 
(red)
```

Now the first four SATA ports work without any problem.
But any device which is connected to the lower four SATA ports are not detected by the computer.

What should I do? Even when I go to the BIOS, it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only the 4 first SATA ports (managed by the ICH7DH) are natively supported in the BIOS and can be used for boot devices.

The 4 ones connected to the Marvell RAID controller require a driver to work. This means they'll be reachable only when an operating system (you don't specifiy which one you use) loads the required driver.